# Make 38, 44, 46 using 2,3,8,7?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Using BODMAS/BIDMAS* and the numbers and signs 2,3,7,8, (), -,+,÷,× can you make 38, 44, 46. You can only use each number once. I can't figure it out myself

Brackets Order Division Multiply Add Subtract/Brackets, Indices, Division and Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction

Comment: Perhaps a bit clearer explanation of what BODMAS/BIDMAS is would be helpful.

Comment: A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bodmas+or+bidmas) indicates that it's an acronym for order of evaluation - Brackets, Order/Indices (exponents and roots), Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction. By implication, those operations are permitted; however, the querent has barred roots by not including the root symbol

Answer (score 8):

The last one was a little bit tricky, I used exponent and non exponent for making 46:

> [image]

Comment: Square root and powers aren't included in the list of allowed operators

Comment: "Orders/Indices"  -- I learned it as BEDMAS, with the E Standing for Exponents.  I'm not sure about the square root though, as that would be another 1/2 in the equation

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I fixed it

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, Is it OK now?

Comment: It's absolutely amazing how we get blinded by "cleverness" and overlook the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

38:

> $(8×3)+(7×2)$

44:

> $(7 - (3/2))×8$

46 (edit):

> With an exhaustive search using a Python script, 46 is impossible without using exponentation/factorials/operators that are disallowed.

Comment: See Seyed's answer.  You're trying too hard!

Comment: @ChrisCudmore to be fair, you said numbers, not digits.

Answer (score 1):

Further to existing answers, 38 is also

> 23+8+7